# Running phantomjs and casperjs

Tags: casperjs

I have followed an tutorial on casperjs ending up with this script:

```
 phantom.casperPath = "/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/";
 phantom.injectJs(phantom.casperPath + "/bin/bootstrap.js");

  var utils = require('utils');

  var casper = require('casper').create();

  casper.start('http://www.google.com');

  casper.wait(3000,function(){

   this.echo(this.getTitle());

   });

   casper.then(function (){
    casper.exit();
  });

casper.run();
```

When I run the script I get this messages:

Error: Cannot find module 'utils'

phantomjs://bootstrap.js:289

phantomjs://bootstrap.js:254 in require

Im running mac os and its pahntomjs and casperjs is both successfully installed; "CasperJS version 1.1.0-beta3 at /usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/libexec, using phantomjs version 1.9.7"﻿

Comment: Does the script work if you don't require utils? What command do you use to run it?

Comment: I run this command "phantomjs casperTest.js" Without requiring utils i get this msg: 
Error: Cannot find module 'casper'

phantomjs://bootstrap.js:289

phantomjs://bootstrap.js:254 in require

Comment: So, none of the modules are accessible. Register to the [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/handler/on-error.html) handler before injecting bootstrap to see if it is actually a problem with the bootstrap code.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the bootstrap code, the msg I get is: PHANTOM ERROR: Error: Cannot find module 'utils'
TRACE:
 -> phantomjs://bootstrap.js: 289
 -> phantomjs://bootstrap.js: 254 (in function require)

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to invoke casperjs this way? Why not install through npm or add phantomjs and casperjs executables to PATH? You should remove `/` at the end of `phantom.casperPath`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install all pre-reqs of phantomjs?

Packages CentOS:

```
gcc gcc-c++ make flex bison gperf ruby \
  openssl-devel freetype-devel fontconfig-devel libicu-devel sqlite-devel \
  libpng-devel libjpeg-devel
```

Packages Ubuntu:

```
build-essential g++ flex bison gperf ruby perl \
  libsqlite3-dev libfontconfig1-dev libicu-dev libfreetype6 libssl-dev \
  libpng-dev libjpeg-dev
```

Second

Why do you need injects the bootstrap? Phantomjs always use the bootstrap.js when run, so you can remove it unless you make some changes in this file.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `/` at the end of `phantom.casperPath`.